# How to include .gitignore in gradle zip task?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have the following gradle (kotlin) code:

```
val zipFiles = fileTree("src/plugin/resources") {
    include("skeletons/common/.gitignore")
    include("skeletons/common/README.md")
}

// Creates the zip file loaded at runtime (we store it under buildDir/assets)
val zipTask = tasks.create<Zip>("zip") {
    from(zipFiles)
    archiveFileName.set(pluginZipFilename)
    destinationDirectory.set(File(buildDir, "assets"))
}
```

No matter what I do, the `.gitignore` file is ignored and does not make it in the zip file. How can I include it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees):

gradle uses a (non published) list of default excludes and in order to change it you have to edit the `settings.gradle.kts` file this way:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner

DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude("**/.gitignore")
```

Note that it becomes global for the entire project and there does not seem to be a way to apply it to a particular file tree.

Comment: wow, what a shame. Thanks for this answer. I ran into this, where I wanted to zip some offline repository and the checksum failed due to some missing gitignore files.